# how to apply plugin from another module

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-plugin

I have two modules app and lib.

I have added a separate file called `plugin.gradle` in lib module that includes a plugin as shown below

```
apply plugin: TestPlugin
class TestPlugin implements Plugin<Project>{

    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.task("test"){
            doLast {

               println "testing"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in order to apply this plugin in lib build.gradle module ,i added the following which works perfectly fine

```
apply from: 'plugin.gradle'
```

however I can't figure out how to apply this plugin into another module (the app module)

Comment: The plugin file you created is in your project root folder, or in your lib's root? If you stick the plugin file in your project's root, you can access it via `apply from: "$rootDir/plugin.gradle"` or something similar.

Comment: Hmm, try this if you want to keep the file in your lib's root directory: `apply from: "${project(':your-lib').projectDir}/plugin.gradle"`

Comment: it's in the lib root

Comment: your second comment worked thx

Comment: Nice, I wasn't 100% sure of the syntax. I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
apply from: "${project(':yourlib').projectDir}/file.gradle"
```

where `yourlib` is the module containing `file.gradle`